# Hide Top Bar in overview

Tags: gnome, 21.10, gnome-shell-extension, gtk4

## What I want to do:

Hide the GNOME Panel while Overview/App Grid is open, but show it on the desktop.  So when I go to my activities overview or look at my apps, the panel is not there.  But when I am looking at the desktop, it is there, and I can interact with it and everything.

## What I've Tried:

I've tried variations of Hide Top Bar extensions without any luck.

## Theoretically

You should be able to make an extension to do this, right?  I have very *very* little knowledge of how to make an extension for GNOME, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it hidden any time? Or only when moving into the overview?

Comment: Only in the overview.  I want it to be shown when the user is on desktop, but hidden in overview.

Comment: Make this more explicit in your question. Hiding in the overview is easy enough, keeping it on the desktop while hiding in the overview is not obvious.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Much clearer now: this will avoid answers to use existing extensions (where I do not see that possibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the native panel

Install Hide Panel extension by fthx

open ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/hide-panel@fthx/extension.js

modify `AppMenu.container.hide()`

```
        this.showing = Overview.connect('showing', this._show_panel.bind(this));
        this.hiding = Overview.connect('hiding', this._hide_panel.bind(this));
```

to

```
        this.showing = Overview.connect('hiding', this._show_panel.bind(this));
        this.hiding = Overview.connect('showing', this._hide_panel.bind(this));
```

Voila.

Now this extension **hides** the panel from overview.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!  This worked like a charm (I also commented the line above it to remove the eyeball icon)

Comment: Would it be possible to also hide the panel in this extension when a window is maximized?

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering only a partial solution which implies the use of dash to panel extension with intellihide ON.

The intellihide works awesome except it **reveals** the panel in overview.

The responsible is `_checkIfShouldBeVisible` in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/intellihide.js`

```
    _checkIfShouldBeVisible: function(fromRevealMechanism) {
        if (Main.overview.visibleTarget || this._dtpPanel.taskbar.previewMenu.opened || 
            this._panelBox.get_hover() || this._checkIfGrab()) {
            return true;
        }
```

Changing the `_checkIfShouldBeVisible` to

```
    _checkIfShouldBeVisible: function(fromRevealMechanism) {
        if (Main.overview.visibleTarget) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (Main.overview.visibleTarget || this._panelBox.get_hover() || this._checkIfGrab() || this._dtpPanel.taskbar.previewMenu.opened) {
            return true;
        }
```

hides the panel from overview.

This works for gnome 3.36, 41 and I believe for all the other versions.

I don't yet know how to use intellihide to interact with the panel for the overview only and it was my main goal. As of now I'm ok with this.

EDIT:

I've found a better solution with intellihide OFF

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js`

`_adjustForOverview: function()`

change

`this.panelBox[isShown ? 'show' : 'hide']();`

to

`this.panelBox[isShown ? 'hide' : 'hide']();`

but now there's no nice smooth animation.. not a big deal I think

Comment: This is not a bad solution, however I would prefer not to use Dash to Panel.  If you know how to do it with a standalone extension, maybe creating one from scratch, then you are very welcome to write another answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by setting this [extention](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/). Try the `sudo apt install gnome-shell` command before installation.

Comment: Well I've tried that extension, as stated in the question.  Also I already have GNOME shell installed, or I wouldn't be able to install the extensions.